# Extract multiple lines on either end of pattern which are enclosed by an identifer

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to extract the trace of a specific event from log files. To find the relevant event, I look for a $PATTERN$. To extract the complete trace of the event, I am looking to extract lines on either end of the pattern enclosed by a $SEPARATOR$

For example, if the contents of log file is

```
Line1
Line2
SEP
Line3
Line4
Name=PATTERN
Line5
SEP
Line 6
...
```

I want to extract

```
SEP
Line3
Line4
Name=PATTERN
Line5
SEP
```

I tried to use sed and got it working for single line matches as below:

```
echo "randomStringSEPrandomPATTERNrandomSEPrandom" | sed -n 's/^.*\(SEP.*PATTERN.*SEP\).*/\1/p'
```

returns `SEPrandomPATTERNrandomSEP`

Any help on how to extend it for multiple lines would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a very natural task for `sed`. Use `awk` instead.

A `gawk`-specific version (thanks Jotne for corrections):

```
gawk -vRS="SEP" '/PATTERN/ {print RT $0 RT}'
```

A version for POSIX awk. Should work on BSD/OSX.

```
awk '
  /SEP/ {
    out = out $0 "\n"
    if (in_seps == 1) {
      if (pattern_found) {
        printf(out)
        pattern_found = 0
      }
      in_seps = 0
      out = ""
    } else
      in_seps = 1
    next
  }

  in_seps == 1 {
    out = out $0 "\n"
  }

  /PATTERN/ {
    pattern_found = 1
  }
'
```

A `sed` script. Uses GNU extension T (like t but opposite condition).

```
sed -n '
  H               # append line to holdspace
  /SEP/ {         # if line was a separator
    x             # exchange pattspace and holdspace
    s/^SEP/&/     # check if it begins with a separator
    T             # if it doesn't, go to next line
    s/PATTERN/&/  # check if it contains the pattern
    T             # if it doesn't, go to next line
    p             # print it
  }
'
```

Comment: Concise and powerful, +1 :)

Comment: and just mention its GNU awk specific due to the multi-char RS. Any other awk would just use `S` as the RS given that command.

Comment: +1; also works with `mawk`, the default on Ubuntu (but not with FreeBSD/OSX `awk`).

Comment: Just a small note. The `gnu awk` does not give exactly what OP requested.  It should also print the `SEP`.  You could do `gawk '/PATTERN/ {print RT $0 RT}' RS="SEP" file`  This will also get rid of the blank line at the end that you get.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` that should work with most version of `awk`

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} s && /^SEP/ {e=NR;next} /^SEP/ {s=NR} /PATTERN/ {f=NR} END {if (f>s && f<e) for (i=s;i<=e;i++) print a[i]}' file
SEP
Line3
Line4
Name=PATTERN
Line5
SEP
```

---

How it works

```
awk '
    {a[NR]=$0}              # Store all line in an array "a"
s && /^SEP/ {               # If flag "s" is true and line starts with "SEP" do
    e=NR                    # set end flag "e" to "NR"
    next}                   # and skip to next line
/^SEP/ {                    # If line starts with "SEP" do
    s=NR}                   # set start flag "s" to "NR"
/PATTERN/ {                 # If line contains "PATTERN" do
    f=NR}                   # set flag "f" to "NR"
END {                       # END section
    if (f>s && f<e)         # If "f" flag is larger than "s" flag and less than "e" flag (pattern within range) do
        for (i=s;i<=e;i++)  # Loop from "s" to "e"
            print a[i]}     # and print the array "a" from this position
    ' file
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>or i miss the purpose or it is a trivial task for sed</s> (from your remark) if like on your sample BUT not if separator is on the same line (like your test)

```
sed -n "/${Separator}/,/${Separator}/ {
   H;g
   /\n${Separator}.*${Separator}$/ {
      s/.\(.*${pattern}.*\)/\1/p
      s/.*//;h
      }
   }" YourFile
```

Assuming Separator does not contain special (Reduced)RegEx char/meaning (not the case with word only content, even alphanum)

If on same line, see other sed reply

Comment: You missed the difficult part. You're only supposed to print what's between the separators if what's between them also contains PATTERN.

Comment: sorry for that, changed the code in post taking that in consideration