# How to remove blocks of text from file

Tags: macos, bash, sed

**EDIT: Did not mentioned before this is to be executed in OS X**

I'm trying to create a bash script which will remove some blocks from a file and save the result to another one.

The file's content I want to filter should look like this:

```
<element>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
</element>
<element>
    <subElement name="removeme"/>
    <subElement name="removeme"/>
    <subElement name="removeme"/>
</element>
<element>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
</element>
```

What I want to remove is the group including the `<element></element>` tags which contains subelements `<subElement name="removeme"/>`

It's guaranteed that no group will have "removeme" and "leaveme" elements mixed.

I know how to do this with a regular expression like this:

```
<element>(?:(?!/elem).)*"removeme".*?</element>
```

but i'm really lost on how to do it in a shell script, had found some info about sed but did not understood how to acomplish that.

Thanks.

Comment: `sed` is not so good for this task. Try `awk` instead. Have a look at Jotne's answer (or possibly mine) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814783/extract-multiple-lines-on-either-end-of-pattern-which-are-enclosed-by-an-identif/24815006?noredirect=1#comment38527405_24815006). It's basically the opposite of what you want but you should be able to adapt it.

Comment: I did look at it but it just uses some separartors to define the removed content, I need to know if the content contains a certain text to determine if remove it or not, is possible to adapt it?

Comment: It uses both separators (like your `<element>` tags) and also content. I think it would be easy to adapt. I'll try it and let you know if it isn't applicable, but I think it is.

Comment: Ok, really appreciate it :D

Comment: Also note glenn jackman's answer, which is really more appropriate and definitely more bulletproof.

Comment: Glenn's response does not work on OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the following (based on Jotne's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814783/extract-multiple-lines-on-either-end-of-pattern-which-are-enclosed-by-an-identif)) is to collect all lines of the file in the `lines` array. The position of the `<element>` and `</element>` tags are saved in `i_start` and `i_end`, respectively.  If `<subElement name="removeme"/>` was seen, `found` is set to `1` (true). `i_end` is conditionally set to either `0` if `found` is true or to the line number (array index) of the end element if `found` is not true. The block between the begin and end tags is printed if `i_end` is not zero.

```
awk '
  { lines[NR] = $0 }
  /<element>/   { i_start = NR }
  /<\/element>/ { i_end = found ? 0 : NR; found = 0 }
  /<subElement name="removeme"\/>/ { found = 1 }
  i_end {
    for (i = i_start; i <= i_end; i++)
      print lines[i]
    i_end = 0;
  }
' file
```

Answer (score 3):

[Regular expressions are certainly the wrong tool to parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552). You want an XML processing tool to remove nodes matching the xpath `//element[subElement[@name="removeme"]]`

- `element` nodes that have a `subElement` child which has a `name` attribute with the value `removeme`

Using [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php):

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//element[subElement[@name="removeme"]]' << ENDXML
<elements>
   <element>
      <subElement name="leaveme"/>
      <subElement name="leaveme"/>
      <subElement name="leaveme"/>
   </element>
   <element>
      <subElement name="removeme"/>
      <subElement name="removeme"/>
      <subElement name="removeme"/>
   </element>
   <element>
      <subElement name="leaveme"/>
      <subElement name="leaveme"/>
      <subElement name="leaveme"/>
   </element>
</elements>
ENDXML
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<elements>
  <element>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
  </element>
  <element>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
  </element>
</elements>
```

Comment: Did try it but no xmlstarlet was found on os x bash, any replacement for it?

Comment: @Gusman You would need to install [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php).

Comment: This is the right way to go, but its not installed in most system by default, and not all user have right to add another tool.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu awk` you can do it like this:

```
awk -v RS="<element>" '!/removeme/ && NR>1{print RS $0}' file
<element>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
</element>

<element>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
    <subElement name="leaveme"/>
</element>
```

By setting the `RS` to `<element>` you are telling `awk` to work in block mode and it starts with `<element>`
Then the `!/removeme/` tells `awk` not to print the block with `removeme` data.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '
    /<element>/h
    /<element>/!H
    /<\/element>/{g;/<subElement name="removeme"\/>/!p;}
' file
```

The `/<element>/h` command initializes on match the hold space with the pattern space contents.

The `/<element>/!H` command appends the pattern space contents to the hold space if the line doesn't match `<element>`.

The `/<\/element>/{g;/<subElement name="removeme"\/>/!p}` command tests for the closing tag and on match executes the two subsequent commands:

1. Populated hold space is copied to the pattern space. Now regular expressions are tested againsts the updated pattern space containing the whole `element` block.
2. Regular expression looks for the filtering subelement value ; on no match, the pattern space gets printed.